# Insert..On Duplicate Key Update is Duplicating Values

Tags: sql, merge, pymysql, upsert

My code is duplicating values when I'm trying to make it update or insert if new.

```
cur.execute("""
INSERT INTO table1(parcel,owner,situsstreet,situscity,mailstreet,mailcity,legal,totaltax,assrparcel,treasacct,schedule) 
SELECT t.parcel,t.owner,t.situsstreet,t.situscity,t.mailstreet,t.mailcity,t.legal,t.totaltax,t.assrparcel,t.treasacct,t.schedule
FROM table2 as t  WHERE assrparcel=t.assrparcel
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE parcel=t.parcel,owner=t.owner,situsstreet=t.situsstreet,situscity=t.situscity,mailstreet=t.mailstreet,mailcity=t.mailcity,legal=t.legal,totaltax=t.totaltax,assrparcel=t.assrparcel,treasacct=t.treasacct,schedule=t.schedule
"""
```

`assrparcel` is unique between tables. Every time I execute it grows the table.  Any idea where my syntax is wrong?

Comment: Most likely, there are records in `table2` that do not yet exist in `table1` at the moment when you run the update query. Try: `select t2.assrparcel from table2 t2 left join table1 t1 on t1.assrparcel = t2.assrparcel where t1.assrparcel is null`.

Comment: *assrparcel is unique between tables*: do you have a unique constraint on this column in each table?

Comment: Please explain exactly what “assrparcel is unique between tables” means

Comment: assrparcel is a unique number/integer that I use as an ID number.  the name assrparcel is the variable name I assigned for it.